# send btc api coinbase?

Tags: php, coinbase-api

I am trying to send satoshis to emails via php with the coinbase api, but it does not work for me. I saw this code online.
I get this error:

```
{"errors": [{"id": "authentication_error", "message": "invalid signature"}]}
```

I attached the php code that I have on my website

```
<?php
$timestamp = time();
$method = 'POST';
$request_path = '/v2/accounts/34en86m3-b0qa-5022-a45c-b110z38631k6/transactions';
$body = 'type=send&to=gabriele.zangari@hotmail.it&amount=0.00002504&currency=BTC';

$account_id = '34en86m3-b0qa-5022-a45c-b110z38631k6';
$hash_input = $timestamp.''.$method.''.$request_path.''.$body;
$apiSecret = 'VmQruPgmAYsW6Pq1vsC5bnzObd5LpTIn';
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $hash_input, $apiSecret, true); 

$accesskey = '1XJZLVA1F4zjQ9cO';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/'.$account_id.'/transactions');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Cb-Access-Key: '.$accesskey;
$headers[] = 'Cb-Access-Sign: '.$signature;
$headers[] = 'Cb-Access-Timestamp: '.$timestamp;
$headers[] = 'Cb-version: 2017-08-07';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
echo $result;
}
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

Note: the key and secret codes posted in the code are invented, but on my website I have the originals.

Comment: `invalid signature` Seems like the error told you what's wrong here. You will have to contact the API support to find out why your credentials aren't working.

Comment: I got in touch with them and they do not give me a solution ... it tells me that there may be some error in the code but they do not tell me what it is.
He told me exactly this:

`This is likely to be the result of your time being for the generation of your timestamp. Keep in mind the time must be within 30 seconds of the API service time. In my experience, that is often caused by invalid API keys.`

But I do not understand very well what you mean ...

Comment: I could solve it, subject resolved.

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Comment: I just posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it this way.

```
          $secret = "fffffffff"; //you number secret
          $timestamp = time();
          $method = "POST";
          $request_path = "/v2/accounts/fffff-fffff-ffff-ffff-ffff/transactions"; //you account id
               
               $data = array (
               'type' => 'send',
               'to' => 'email@gmail.com',  //put email
               'amount' => '0.0000012'), //put amount
               'currency' => 'BTC',  //put crypto
               'description' => 'put you description', //put description
                );
               $body = json_encode($data);
               $prehash = $timestamp.$method.$request_path.$body;
               $sign = hash_hmac("sha256", $prehash, $secret);
               $ch = curl_init();
               $headers = array(
               'CB-ACCESS-KEY: fffffffffff', //You Key
               'CB-ACCESS-SIGN: '.$sign,
               'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP: '.$timestamp,
               'CB-ACCESS-VERSION: 2018-05-20',
               'Content-Type: appliaction/json'
               );
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
               curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.coinbase.com'.$request_path);
               $res = curl_exec($ch);
```